# Why are closed intervals used when Lagrange's Theorem for the the Remainder is applied to a definite integral?

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, mean-value-theorem

[image]
For the solution to part b) of this question, they've written that 0≤c≤1. From my understanding of Lagrange's Remainder Theorem, the interval for the c term arises from the Mean Value Theorem, thus shouldn't open intervals be used? 0<c<1. Have they written a mistake here?

Furthermore, if we were to consider their final step of working (which I am curious to know why it is even necessary—aren't they making interval estimate less accurate?): ½(e - e^-1) < ½(3-⅓) = 4/3, wouldn't this imply E < 4/3 × 1/(15•7!) and not E ≤ 4/3 × 1/(15•7!) ?

Comment: If $0 < c < 1$ is true then $0 \le c \le 1$ is also true, so they haven't made a mistake - they just haven't written the strongest possible statement.  Sure, with that change they could prove $E < 0.0000176\dots$ instead of $E \le 0.0000176\dots$, but there isn't any practical difference between those.  It seems very unlikely that any application of this fact would hinge on whether or not $E$ could equal the exact value $0.0000176\dots$.

Comment: There is a mean value theorem for integrals where the value is in the closed interval. It may be that the remainder formula they are using here was derived with that version of the mean value theorem.